# Using only part of a less stylesheet

Tags: less

Let's say I have a less stylesheet with a lot of styles in it, and I want to copy a few other to a new sheet, like so:

**huge-stylesheet.less**:

```
/*

blah blah blah for dozens of styles

*/
.loopy {
    color: greenyellow
}
```

**tiny-stylesheet.less**:

```
.froopy {
    .loopy
}
```

Is it possible for me to set it up so that when compiled, tiny-stylesheet.css *just* has the .froopy style defined and not everything else that's in huge-stylesheet.less?

Comment: hmm, why not to transfer that tiny piece of less to new file, and include that file instead of big one?

Comment: It's not *that* tiny. In this case, huge-stylesheet.less is actually bootstrap. And I'd like to copy just a few of the styles over to an add-on stylesheet that is used in some parts of a website but not all of them. So for example, I might want to copy over some of the mixins, etc. over to this file.

Comment: since stylesheets get cahched by the browser, I think it would be better to just include the huge stylesheet everywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer for LESS 1.5

You can now import a file as a reference in LESS 1.5. So

```
@import (reference) "huge-stylesheet";
```

Which gives you access to *use any and all* the LESS in **huge-stylesheet.less** without *outputting* any of it into **tiny-stylesheet.less**.

You should then just be able to do as you originally intended:

```
.froopy {
    .loopy;
}
```

### Original Answer

Yes, it is possible "that when compiled, tiny-stylesheet.css just has the .froopy style defined and not everything else" by using namespaces. You may need to set up the namespace in separate file (say *master.less*) like this:

```
#yourNameSpace() {
    your huge code that was in huge-stylesheet 
}
```

And then use another file to produce **huge-stylesheet.less** like this:

```
@import "master"; 
#yourNameSpace; //call the code to produce the huge sheet
```

And use it in **tiny** like this:

```
@import "master";
.froopy {
    #yourNameSpace > .loopy;
}
```

Or you might try leaving the code as is in the **huge** sheet and do this in the **tiny-stylesheet.less** (I have not played with importing to know if it can be nested in a block):

```
#yourNameSpace() {
    @import "huge-stylesheet"; 
}

.froopy {
    #yourNameSpace > .loopy;
}
```

Either way, it will only extract the code `.loopy` from the namespace. No other final CSS code is generated from the namespace code by the **tiny** LESS file.